# Problema al hacer un DELETE con la clausula LIMIT en una consulta SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

La siguiente consulta me borra los datos coincidentes con la búsqueda de mi base de datos pero yo solo quiero que me borre una sola fila en caso de que la consulta coincida con más de una fila de mi tabla.
Según lo que entiendo la consulta estaría bien hecha, con el `LIMIT 1` pero al ejecutarla me arroja la siguiente excepción:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' 
occurred in System.Data.SQLite.dll

Additional information: SQL logic error

near "LIMIT": syntax error
```

Esta es mi consulta:

```
private void Pagos_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Pagos.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "colBotones")
    {
        string mesa = this.numMesa.Trim();
        int id_producto = Convert.ToInt32(this.Pagos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        string nombre = Convert.ToString(this.Pagos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        double precio = Convert.ToDouble(this.Pagos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        double cantidad = Convert.ToDouble(this.Pagos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
        double subtotal = Convert.ToDouble(this.Pagos.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString());

        String consulta = "DELETE FROM Productos where mesa = @mesa and @id_producto = id_producto and nombre = @nombre and precio = @precio and cantidad = @cantidad and subtotal = @subtotal LIMIT 1";
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(consulta, conexion);

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@id_producto", id_producto));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@nombre", nombre));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@precio", precio));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@cantidad", cantidad));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@subtotal", subtotal));

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Pagos.Rows.RemoveAt(Pagos.CurrentRow.Index);
    }
}
```

¿ Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando ?

Comment: Me da que `LIMIT`en `DELETE`no se puede usar.

Comment: Si tienes este problema, me temo que debes revisar el diseño de tus tablas. Como bien te han dicho no puedes usar `LIMIT` en un `DELETE`, pero no parece muy lógico que tengas varias filas en las que todas las columnas sean iguales..

Comment: es logico tener varias filas iguales en mi diseño, ya que se ingresan textos en varios textboxes y luego estos van a la base de datos. Es posible que una mesa tenga cargado el mismo producto, la misma cantidad del mismo y con el mismo precio y se necesite borrar una sola fila de por ejemplo coca-cola y no todas las filas que coincidan. Pero es por tema de diseño, apurado sobre todo al ser para la facu. Mil gracias a todos :)

Comment: Todas las tablas deben tener un id único, normalmente autonumérico. De esa manera, todas difieren y si quieres eliminar una fila, accedes a ella por su id. No,no es lógico tener varias filas identicas en ninguna tabla :)

Comment: Lo voy a tener en cuenta para la proxima Pikoh ! La verdad que lo hice así para salir del paso, sino tengo que estar preguntando cada dos por tres en la página como hacer algo y tengo miedo de que algún día me dejen de contestar jajaja ... especialmente VOS :P

Comment: Aqui siempre habrá gente dispuesta a ayudar, no te preocupes por eso :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la clausula LIMIT no puedes aplicarla en un delete de esta forma.
Una forma de usarla seria como el siguiente esquema:

```
Delete from table_name where rowid IN (Select rowid from table_name limit X);
```

Espero que pueda ayudarte a solucionar el problema.